# CL604/650 (or CRJ1/2) max loiter time (using it as a reference point to compare the A-10 to)

Tags: aircraft-performance, bombardier-crj, fairchild-a-10

In some discussions I was having with a (back-office) USAF acquaintance about the F-35 vs. A-10 debate, the topic of loiter time came up.  [Wikipedia provides a 1.88 hour (112min) loiter time for the A-10 at a 250nmi combat radius with what appears to be a CAS loadout and a 5000' loiter altitude.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_Republic_A-10_Thunderbolt_II#Specifications_(A-10A))  However, I'm not sure how heavily that is influenced by altitude (obviously, being at 5000' doesn't help *any* jet's gas mileage) vs. how much of that is being influenced by being a very "dirty" airframe laden with draggy protuberances and external stores.

So, given that the [CL601/604/650 and CRJ100/200 have a similar MTOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_Challenger_600_series#CL-604) and [basically identical engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_CF34) to the A-10 on a relatively "clean" airframe, assuming you had some reason to send a laden CRJ boring circles over some spot 250 nmi away at 5000' for a while (maybe it's carrying some sort of scientific payload internally), and were limited to 11klbs of fuel in doing so, how long would that CRJ be able to loiter before the flight crew had to start turning back home?

Comment: Does the A-10 switch an engine off when loitering? Not so uncommon with dual engine aircraft.

Comment: Once you're in the loiter area, the cleanliness isn't that much an issue because you're just talking about time in the air at min fuel flow, and whether that's achieved at 220 kt or 240 kt doesn't make much difference except on the trip to and from the loiter area. I dimly recall the 3B1 uses about 1100-1300 pph and maybe can be coaxed down to about 1000 pph if you slow to min drag, like .6+M.  But that's in the FLs. Down at 5000 ft it's gonna be 13-1500 pph (wild guess).  So 11k lbs might give you maybe 4+ hrs, so with 2 hrs transit and 1 hr reserve would give an hour, maybe 2, on station.